# How to do a dry run in root folder?

Tags: magento2, script, code, debug, file

Is there  way to do a dry run within your root folder to make sure the line of code works

Comment: Can you please describe your question so it's helpful to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Create A file test.php on your Magento2 root folder.

```
<?php
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    include('app/bootstrap.php');
    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
    $objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    /* impliment your code here which you want to test*/
```

You can impliment your testing code using object manager directly.